# Android WebView JavaScript onClick Bug

Tags: javascript, android, css

I have some `JavaScript` which adds some `CSS` when a button is clicked using the `onClick()` event. This works perfectly in all the browsers that have tested (Safari, Firefox, Chrome etc), and also works on all mobiles including within the `iOS` `UIWebView` object.

However although it works perfectly in the Google Chrome browser on an android phone it does not work within the Android `WebView` object. Nothing happens at all.

Changing it from an `onClick()` event to a `touchstart()` event works.

Also adding `alert()` inside the `onClick()` works too, it just seems that the `onClick()` event is incapable of adding `CSS` styling inside the Android `WebView` object

What the hell is going on, is this some kind of bug, it seems to happen on every Android mobile I have test on, all with a different OS version :S

Here is the code I have been using

```
if (login) {
    login.addEvent('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('login_items_wrapper').setStyle('opacity', '0');
        $('loading_content_login').show();
    });
}
```

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

I tried this "duplicate version" in nature JS and it's work for me:

```
if (login) {
    login.onclick = myFunc();
    login.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myFunc();
    });
}

function myFunc() {
    $('.login_items_wrapper').setStyle('opacity', '0');
    $('.loading_content_login').show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change

```
$('login_items_wrapper').setStyle('opacity', '0');
$('loading_content_login').show();
```

to

```
$('.login_items_wrapper').setStyle('opacity', '0');
$('.loading_content_login').show();
```

or

```
$('#login_items_wrapper').setStyle('opacity', '0');
$('#loading_content_login').show();
```

As you are not correctly referencing the elements.

Comment: Nope, that is not it unfortunately, I am using mootools so $('someid') is correct syntax for collecting an element by ID. There is nothing wrong with the element selection anyway as it works for every other browser, just not inside the android WebView

Comment: Although it won't help too much you should mention mootools so that if someone comes along and can help you won't get the wrong idea like i did.